# Conseguir el valor de una tabla php

Tags: php, mysqli, login

Actualmente estoy haciendo un php para hacer un login y redirigir a los usuarios, si el login coincide y aparece, entonces pasa a comprobar si es admin o no, para ello, debe la consulta devolverle en el select el role, la duda es, como consigo sacar el role y después compararlo con un if?

```
<?php
//Login en la base de datos 
$servername = "xxx";
$username = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";
$dbname = "xxx";

//Coge las variables del ajax
$email = $_POST["email"];
$contraseña = $_POST['password'];
// Crea una nueva conexion
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Comprueba la conexion
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$total = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($conn," SELECT email FROM USUARIOS where email = '$email' and password = '$contraseña'"));
    if($total == 1){

        $admin = $conn,"SELECT role FROM USUARIOS where email = '$email' and password = '$contraseña'" ->get_result() ;
        if( $admin == 'admin'){
 echo "U are a admin user" . $admin;
            header('Location: ../admin.html');
        } else {
            echo "U are a normal user" . $admin; 
header('Location: ../user.html');
        }
    }else{
        echo "Error login";
    }

$conn->close();

?>
```

De momento es lo que tengo hecho (acepto modificaciones o explicaciones también de otras cosas ya que lo estoy haciendo como puedo)

Comment: puedes indicarnos la definicion de tu tabla Usuarios? por lo que parece, en la misma tabla tienes el role del usuario, asi que la primera consulta podrias simplificarla cogiendo tanto el email como el role... Por otra parte, revisa en stackoverflow, que hay varias respuestas sobre como leer de una bbdd con php, ok?

Comment: Te doy un consejo aunque no va con la pregunta. Siempre pon un cifrado a la contraseña del usuario, ya que almacenar texto en plano en la contraseña no es seguro.

Comment: Otra cosa que deberías tomar en cuenta es no mandar a ejecutar nunca consultas de este tipo: `SELECT email FROM USUARIOS where email = '$email' and password = '$contraseña'`, porque las variables `$email` y `$contraseña` podrían ser modificadas por usuarios mal intencionados cambiándolas por código que podría encadenar otras consultas para borrar/modificar/insertar/obtener datos sensibles, o incluso para ejecutar comandos dañinos en tu propio sistema. Es lo que se conoce como **Inyección SQL** y que deberías prevenir usando **consultas preparadas**. Ponlo *en carpeta* para un futuro no lejano.

Comment: @AnonimoPer Alguna guia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías hacer todo en una misma query, en lugar de dividirlo en dos.

Intenta cambiar esto:

```
$total = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($conn," SELECT email FROM USUARIOS 
where email = '$email' and password = '$contraseña'"));
if($total == 1){

    $admin = $conn,"SELECT role FROM USUARIOS where email = '$email' and 
password = '$contraseña'" ->get_result() ;
    if( $admin == 'admin'){
echo "U are a admin user" . $admin;
        header('Location: ../admin.html');
    } else {
        echo "U are a normal user" . $admin; 
header('Location: ../user.html');
    }
}else{
    echo "Error login";
}
```

por esto:

```
$query = "SELECT role FROM USUARIOS where email = '$email' and password = '$contraseña'";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
//num_rows regresa el numero de filas del resultado del query.
if($result->num_rows == 1){
//fetch_assoc regresa el resultado como un associative array, o diccionario.
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$role = $row['role'];
if($role == 'admin') {
    echo "U are a admin user". $role;
    header('Location: ../admin.html');
} else {
    echo "U are a normal user" . $role;
    header('Location: ../user.html');
}

} else{
   echo "Error login";
}
```

No lo he probado, pero debería ser algo por el estilo.

Comment: Había pensado lo mismo, al fin y al cabo la "doble consulta" la única función que tenía era contar el numero de resultados para luego lanzar prácticamente la misma consulta de nuevo. Buena aportación ;)